# Can't print to pdf using tcpdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I have configured TCPDF library to print page to pdf. But When I am doing print, it gives some error

```
 Undefined index: old_cell_padding
 Undefined index: colid
```

Why this?

Comment: You've been here long enough to know you need to post more relevant code than that.

Comment: The error messages should have given you a file name and a line number. The additional information is kind of a big deal...

Comment: `Undefined index` is displayed when you try to access an array element which does not exist.